# Getting window.scrollTo(0, 0); to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrollto

I know that this problem got probably asked and solved a thousand times, yet I need advice on my specific case.

I've set several anchors on my website and I'm using jquery to smoothly scroll between them. I've been using a `#top` anchor to scroll to the top of the page and it works. The problem is, however, that if I let the button scroll to #top it won't scroll to the absolute top of the page (since I can't set the anchor high enough on the webpage).

I tried to get it work with the `window.scrollTo(0, 0);` command, but I don't know how to get it to work while still having the possibility to scroll to anchors.

I used the following jQuery for the anchor-scrolling:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var target = this.hash;
        var $target = $(target);

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
        }, 900, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });
});
```

With this HTML:

```
<a href="#top">
    <img alt="" heigth="60" onmouseout="this.src='http://i.imgur.com/0JvWWER.png'" onmouseover="this.src='http://i.imgur.com/Ow7CVn0.png'" src="http://i.imgur.com/0JvWWER.png" width="60" />
</a>
```

Now, how do I get the `window.scrollTo(0,0);` to work and how do I implement it in the html body?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Give the `<body>`, an `id="top"` and try?

Comment: `var $target = target === '#top' ? 0 : $(target).offset().top;` will fix that for you, you do not even need an anchor.

Comment: Thank you, worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [somethinghere](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2991619/somethinghere) says, do a small change here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var target = $(this).attr("href");

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            // Change here...
            'scrollTop': ((target === '#top') ? 0 : $(target).offset().top)
        }, 900, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Why not drop `$target` altogether and only initiate it when you need it? Would save a _tiny_ amount of resources, but it does remove on line and a jQuery call (on a case by case basis).

Comment: @somethinghere Good idea too.

Comment: @somethinghere Check if that's okay?

Comment: Yeah I think it does. If `this.hash` worked, btw (I'm unsure what it does here), then that would have been fine too. But yeah, this is a minor save of resources :)

Comment: @somethinghere LoL. That's fine... Gave you credits in my answer too.